# Variable gets overridden in loop

Tags: python, list, loops

Consider the following for-loop:

```
def function(list, x, y):
   list[x] = y
   print(list)

list = [1,2,3]

for i in range(3):
   copyOfList = list
   function(copyOfList, i, 100)
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```
> [100, 2, 3]
> [1, 100, 3]
> [1, 2, 100]
```

**Why?**

Everytime before I run `function`, I do reinitialize `copyOfList` like this:

`copyOfList = list`

But Python gives me the following output:

```
> [100, 2, 3]
> [100, 100, 3]
> [100, 100, 100]
```

How can I achieve the desired output, and what is the reason behind Pythons output?

Comment: `copyOfList` isn't a copy. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @j1-lee Thats fair. I just wanted to give an minimal example to illustrate my real issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested links. I will look into that.

Comment: `copyOfList = list` **does not create a copy**